# ¿Como cambiar la contraseña de una clave SSH cifrada?

Tags: shell, ssh

Después de crear una clave SSH se da la opción de protegerla con una contraseña. ¿Como puedo cambiar o quitar esa contraseña si he cambiado de opinión teniendo la contraseña antigua?

He usado este comando para crear la clave:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "mye@mail.com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Tampoco es factible crear otra clave, ya que la tengo en Github y varios sitios mas como mi única clave publica.

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar la contraseña de una clave SSH que está protegida se usa:

```sh
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

Según la ayuda del comando `ssh-keygen`

```sh
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1]
              [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```